# Delete button activation in Java GUI

Tags: java, methods

I'm building a java application where i want to delete some info that are already added. the user enters their name,ID,GPA and after they add them, incase they want to delete it all they have to do is enter the name and if the record exists, the student will  be deleted.
my problem is I tested the method that I will enter shortly, and it has worked on running the main function without the gui, but whenever I try to connect the method to the delete button,, the method doesn't work properly.

**here is the main method function call**

```
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

                String name = txt2.getText();

                removeStudent(name);

            }
        });
```

**here is the function that is defined and tested**

```
        Student newStudent = Student.createStudent(name, " ", " ");
        String studentName = newStudent.getName();
        Student existingStudentRecord = studentInfoSystem.queryStudent(studentName);
        if (existingStudentRecord == null) {
            System.out.println("Student not found");
            return;
        }
        if (studentInfoSystem.removeStudent(existingStudentRecord)) {
            System.out.println("successfully deleted");

        } else System.out.println("Error deleting the student...");
    }
```

note the method works properly but there is something I'm doing wrong probably when I'm calling the function in the main.
if someone has any solution please tell me.

Comment: Could you please share a simplified version of your code that compiles and can be run by others to check for the exact place of the error.

Comment: Why do you need to do `Student newStudent = Student.createStudent(name, " ", " ");` when all you need is the name, which has already been passed to you?  This would seem to be creating another student with the specified name ... which could then be what is getting removed